# Is there a way to make a DIV unselectable?

Tags: css

I have a textarea with a transparent background overlaying some *text* that I'd like to use as a sort of watermark.  The text is large and takes up a majority of the textarea.  It looks nice, but the problem is when the user clicks in the textarea it sometimes selects the watermark text instead.

I want the watermark text to never be selectable.  I was expecting if something was lower in the z-index it would not be selectable, but browsers don't seem to care about z-index layers when selecting items.  Is there a trick or way to make it so this DIV is never selectable?

Answer (score 245):

I wrote a simple jQuery extension to disable selection some time back: [Disabling Selection in **jQuery**](http://aleembawany.com/2009/01/20/disable-selction-on-menu-items-with-this-jquery-extension/). You can invoke it through `$('.button').disableSelection();`

Alternately, using CSS (cross-browser):

```css
.button {
        user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: @kasperTaeymans But it is in a [W3C working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select)... I'd include it just in case.

Comment: Not to take anything away from the original answer, which I upvoted, but it is 3+ years old. So I added an answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable/24831222#24831222) with an added setting for touch interface.

Comment: That's what I wanted for movable bootstrap modal header! Thanks!

Answer (score 72):

The following CSS code works in almost all modern browsers:

```css
.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

For [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer), you must use JavaScript or insert an attribute in the HTML tag.

```html
<div id="foo" unselectable="on" class="unselectable">...</div>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `unselectable="on"`. Can you give a reference please

Comment: I found at here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801966(v=vs.85).aspx

But I actually tested on IE, and it works correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure. But <code>unselectable="on"</code> might be included on IE, and W3C validator does not accept that attribute.

Comment: While it works on modern browsers, it is not yet specified by W3C.

Answer (score 54):

#### An update [aleemb's original, much-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable/924937#924937) with a couple of additions to the CSS

We've been using the following combination:

```
.unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

We got the suggestion for adding the webkit-touch entry from:
*[Essential PhoneGap CSS: WebKit Touch Callout](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/essential-phonegap-css-webkit-touch-callout.html)*

2015 Apr: Here is a variation that may come in handy. If you need to make the DIV selectable/unselectable on the fly and are willing to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), the following works neatly in JavaScript:

```
    var userSelectProp = Modernizr.prefixed('userSelect');
    var specialDiv = document.querySelector('#specialDiv');
    specialDiv.style[userSelectProp] = 'none';
```

Comment: applying `user-select: none` to a `div` has no effect whatsoever. i'm pretty sure `user-select` is for text only.  are there any other ways to make a `div` unselectable?

Answer (score 25):

You can use `pointer-events: none;` in your CSS

```
div {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to avoid my <hr/> grabbing the selection from a hidden div. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

As [Johannes has already suggested](https://stackovQerflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable/924934#924934), a background image is probably the best way to achieve this in CSS alone.

A JavaScript solution would also have to affect "dragstart" to be effective across all popular browsers.

JavaScript:

```
<div onselectstart="return false;" ondragstart="return false;">your text</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var _preventDefault = function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); };
$("div").bind("dragstart", _preventDefault).bind("selectstart", _preventDefault);
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple background image for the textarea may suffice.

Comment: Well, I rather meant the watermark, but a transparent background image might work as well. Also you shouldn't tile very small images as some browsers get abysmally slow in that case :)

Comment: Especially since a 1000x1000 transparent png (or gif) is only 4kb.

Comment: More like 1 KiB, actually :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
<div onselectstart="return false">your text</div>
```

Comment: It is still possible to select with double click.

Answer (score 5):

[WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) browsers (i.e., [Google Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) and [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29)) have a CSS solution similar to Mozilla's `-moz-user-select: none`:

```
.no-select{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor:not-allowed; /* Makes it even more obvious */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also in iOS if you want to get rid of gray semi-transparent overlays appearing ontouch, add this CSS content:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are multiple ways.

1. You could simply add the `user-select` CSS declaration and set it to `none`, like this

   ```
   div {
       user-select: none;
   }
   ```
2. Also you could accomplish this with the CSS `::selection` selector and set the selection background color to match your own. This could get tricky.:

   ```
   p::selection {
       background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
   }
   ```

Option 1 being the best option in most cases for obvious reasons!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you set position explicitly as absolute or relative for z-index to work for selection.  I had a similar issue and this solved it for me.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
onselectstart="return false"
```

It prevents copying your content.

Comment: This solution has been posted by others.

Comment: No need for any JS at all. The best answer with the element being non-selectable via CSS is pretty good.