# Making an element unselectable using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

What's the best way to make an element unselectable using jQuery?

I know you can use `onselectstart="return false;" ondragstart="return false;"` in the HTML, but I'm not sure how cross browser compatible that is.

I also see someone's made a jQuery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Unselectable .. would a plugin like that be necessary?

Is there a simple, compatible way to make an element unselectable?

The reason for wanting to do this is purely aesthetic. With webpages that have dragging or click events, it's not very nice when things get selected.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable - Just noticed the question asks for a CSS solution but the majority of answers are JavaScript/jQuery based.  Specifically, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable/924951#924951

Comment: Thanks, that's basically the same solution CodeJoust gave, although CJ's version is more compact :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('.noselect').live('selectstart dragstart', function(evt){ evt.preventDefault(); return false; });`

Just bind the event to a live, and return false, or prevent default.

Comment: That's a really nice, concise solution!

Comment: Thanks!
Do realize that the plugin also uses CSS techniques and might be a little more bulletproof, so to say.
However, if it isn't mission-critical, I prefer concision over unnecessarily complex code, usually something like this is just to improve the User Interface.

Comment: live() is deprecated in new version of jQuery. Use "on()" instead

Comment: Keep in mind, this won't solve the issue if the `dragstart` event is fired outside the element.

Answer (score 1):

I think jQuery will abstract the browser variance & so it will help you make HTML elements unselectable.

Having said that, please note that the client can decide to switch off javascript, in which case you need to ensure that he still cannot do anything that will cause harm...

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a better answer.

```
$('*[data-noselect="true"]').focus(
    function () {
        $(this).blur();
    });

$('*[data-noselect="true"] *').focus(
    function () {
        $(this).blur();
    });
```

Then you can just add a `data-noselect="true"` to any element.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) you can set `class="ui-state-default"` to the div that you dont want to be selected.

```
<div class="ui-state-default"></div>
```

Comment: This is only appropriate for elements already styled by JQuery UI, however.