# How can I make MANY elements unselectable using jQuery or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make a DIV unselectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable)

I have seen a number of solutions out there that work for an element. However I have an area with labels and buttons. It's not just one element it's every element within a `DIV`.

How can I make anything contained within that `DIV` unselectable? Note that I cannot just put a mask layer over the `DIV` as the `DIV` has buttons I need to be able to click.

Comment: Did you try using $(this).each(function(){ //disable what you want });

Comment: doesn't setting parent unselectable work? All children should be included. Other wise try selector `mydivclass *`

Comment: From what I read unselectable is not inherited

Comment: It's not a duplicate as the previous question is for a DIV. My question is for everything inside a DIV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".yourdiv").children().css({userSelect: 'none'});
```

That's in case you want to disable selection using the CSS `user-select` property. If not, the above can be easily generalized to other methods.

The above only selects direct children, to select **all** descendants, use the `.find()` method:

```
$(".yourdiv").find("*").css({userSelect: 'none'});
```

You can also do this using pure CSS:

```
.yourdiv * { /*this selects all elements that are children of yourdiv*/
    /*user-select: none rules*/
}
```

Or:

```
.yourdiv > * { /*this selects all elements that are direct descendants of yourdiv*/
    /*user-select: none rules*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How could I extend it to also do the other properties: -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;

Comment: `$(".yourdiv *")` would cover all descendents not just children

Comment: @SamanthaJ New versions of jQuery automatically add prefixes if needed.

Comment: Do you think this would be an expensive operation if it covers many elements?

Comment: could add class to parent and do the rest with css

Comment: @SamanthaJ See edit for a note.

Comment: @SamanthaJ See updated answer for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Could I just do this to the body? Note that I never want the user to be able to select anything.

Comment: @SamanthaJ Sure, just replace `.yourdiv` in the examples above with `body`.

Comment: This doesn't work for Opera or IE < 10, which don't support CSS `-x-user-select` properties.

Comment: @TimDown Well, I believe the main reason the OP is asking the question is how to apply the rule on all child elements, not how to actually make an element unselectable. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
div.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foo" class="unselectable">...</div>
```

Reference:

- [Is there a way to make a DIV unselectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable)
- [Disabling Selection in jQuery](http://aleembawany.com/2009/01/20/disable-selction-on-menu-items-with-this-jquery-extension/)

Answer (score 1):

The proprietary `user-select` CSS variations are inherited in all browsers that support them. See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/yD7bM/

Your problem is the browsers that do not support these CSS properties, namely Opera and IE <= 9. Happily both of these implement an alternative: the [`unselectable` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, it is this attribute that is not inherited.

The best solution is to put an `unselectable="on"` attribute on every element that you require to be unselectable in the HTML (i.e. do it server-side). However, if this is not an option, you can do it using JavaScript using [a recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358620/96100).

If you're using jQuery you could do something like this to add the `unselectable` attribute to each element with class "unselectable" and all of its descendants:

```
 $(".unselectable").find("*").andSelf().attr("unselectable", "on");
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ulazic/2

Comment: Can you, please, point to any documentation on `unselectable` attribute?

Comment: Uhh, what about browser support?

Comment: @Pavlo: IE 5.5+, Opera 8 or 9+ (can't find official docs for Opera).

Comment: @Pavlo: Some searching reveals Opera has had it since 2006 or earlier, suggesting support was added in Opera 9.

Comment: IE 10 doesn't support those CSS properties either.

Comment: @VoidKing: IE 10 supports `-ms-user-select`: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/

Comment: @TimDown Guess I messed something up, when last I tried. I stand corrected.

Comment: @TimDown Actually, I have IE 10 and the text is very much still selectable after applying `-ms-user-select` to the same element that when I assign the attribute `unselectable` the text therein can't be selected. I have never, in any version of IE 10, 9, 8 or below, gotten this so-called CSS rule to apply to IE, no matter the circumstance, no matter how clear the cache is, etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @VoidKing: Not sure what you're doing wrong. The following works for me in IE 10, provided it's not in any compatibility mode: http://jsfiddle.net/hBDZe/1/

Comment: @TimDown Wierd, your jsfiddle works for me, but if I implement the same exact rule `-ms-user-select: none;` it doesn't work for me. I always use them to make `<button>` elements (which I always assumed would apply to the text therein) it most certainly does not work in IE 10. However, if I assign `unselectable="on"` to the same element, it works like a charm. Perhaps there is some restriction with this CSS rule working with button elements. As for compatibility mode, I'm not sure, but I'm running IE 10 out of the box, which means my users will also, so either way on that one.