# Disable an element from getting selected - Jquery & CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following html -:

```
<div contenteditable="true">Hey man <a class="ddt">Harry</a></div>
```

I would want that the user is not able to select the `a.ddt` element. In simple words, all other contents inside the div can be selected, but the `a.ddt` cannot be selected.

How do i do this... Thanks for help.

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by selected? do you mean that the user should not be able to click the link? Or the user should not be able to tab to the link? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

[Disabling Selection in jQuery](http://aleembawany.com/2009/01/20/disable-selction-on-menu-items-with-this-jquery-extension/),
Can be invoked through $('.button').disableSelection();

Alternately, using CSS (cross-browser):

> .button {
>
> ```
>     -moz-user-select: none; 
>     -khtml-user-select: none; 
>     -webkit-user-select: none; 
>     -o-user-select: none;  }
> ```

original post by [aleemb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add such a limitation on the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about diabling selection using mouse?

If yes, then you should see this

[How to disable text selection using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery)

Comment: This is not an answer. Please use comment section