# How to make web page element not highlight on select all command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have the following simple structure on my page:

```
<div class="logo">
   <img src="logo.jpeg" alt="logo"/>
</div>
```

When previewing my page in Chrome hitting `cmd+A` (select all), the image block becomes highlighted. Here's a visual example:

[image]

How can I prevent selected element to not highlight like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a DIV unselectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.user-select-none {
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-select-none">
  You can not drag this.
</div>
<div class="user-select-on">
  You can drag this.
</div>
```

Comment: It's good for Ctrl+A on Windows but what about mouse selection.