# Is it possible to limit text selection to current element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="container">
<div class="item1">text text text in div 1</div>
<div class="item2">text text text in div 2</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible (by any HTML node, CSS or JS) to prevent from selecting text in div.item2 if selection started from text in div.item1 and the other way around - starting from div.item2 and limit to it (prevent item1 form being selected)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a DIV unselectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable)

Comment: So, the only way is to add user-select: none to item2 if click event is triggered on item1 and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this, with a bit of jQuery code :

```js
let $items = $(".item")

$items
 .mousedown( function() {
  $(this).siblings().css({ "user-select" : "none" , color : "lightgrey"}) 
 })
 .mouseup( function() {
  $items.css({ "user-select" : "auto" , color : "black"}) 
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="item">text text text in div 1</div>
 <div class="item">text text text in div 2</div>
 <div class="item">text text text in div 3</div>
 <div class="item">text text text in div 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a tiny issue :) if you start the selection outside from the bottom you can select all of them

Comment: @JeremyThile and also doesn't work if structure is table IMAO

Comment: Of course it doesn't work if the structure is a table. You never talked about a table... but now you have a working example, you get the idea, you can adapt it to a table :)

Comment: @Temani You're right, but OP's question is explicitely about starting within div1 or div2 and preventing the selection of others.

Answer (score 1):

The `user-select: contain` option does this. Unfortunately, it is only supported by ... IE???

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select#browser_compatibility

Comment: Specifically the version that IE supports is actually called `user-select: element`. There's not much point in including it as a fallback though since there's not many IE / Old Edge users left

Comment: At least in chrome, the selection is limited to the current element with `user-select:all` as wel

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved the issue for my purposes...

I had several scrollable div's (with class `txt`), within which the user is allowed to select text — but only within one div at a time (and no other text on the page should be selectable). So, I used css:

```css
*,.noSelect{ user-select:none; }
.txt{ user-select:text; }
```

...and then listen for the [`selectstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/selectstart_event) event, to grab the ID of the element where selection begins, and immediately disable selection in all the others:

```js
document.addEventListener('selectstart',function(e){
  var selStartID=window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.id;
  $('.txt').each(function(){
    if(this.id!=selStartID){$(this).addClass('noSelect');}
  });
});
```

...then, after you're finished doing whatever you're doing with the selection (copying/saving/etc), you can re-enable selection in all the other elements:

```
$('.noSelect').removeClass('noSelect');
```

---

### Coming in CSS4? **`user-select: contain;`**

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/user-select), CSS UI 4 will simplify this with [`user-select: contain;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)... Currently only supported in IE <sup><sub>*[Words you don't often hear!]*</sub></sup>. There's a [polyfill on github](https://github.com/github/user-select-contain-polyfill) — though I haven't tried it.

<sub>(css-tricks.com has a different opinion about [CSS4](https://css-tricks.com/css4/), and Wikipedia's got [another story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS#CSS_4) about it.)</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way is using CSS:

```css
.item1 {
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item1"> Unselectable text</div>
<div class="item2"> Selectable text</div>
```

Comment: Already posted then removed. How do you start from div2 and prevent div1 selection?

Comment: Just copy this code to an empty `.html` and run it!

Comment: I did better. I made a runnable snippet with your code so you can see it doesn't work :)

Comment: You can change CSS properties dynamically. Also if you start from item2 (bottom to up) item1 is still unselectable. What is wrong with this code then?