# Text selection error on mobile with "select all"

Tags: html, css, text, textselection

The "select all" function in my HTML site on mobile devices (and CTRL+A on windows) is selecting all the text of the entire site instead of just the current paragraph. This behavior is unacceptable and must be avoided. Is there a way to limit the "select all" function to only select text within the current paragraph? I have not found any solutions online, but it seems strange to me that this behavior would be preferred by anyone.

Comment: I'll give you the website link directly. If you try a "select all" you will see that all text on the page will be selected. https://manux895.github.io/EsameDiStato/

Comment: Something like this may work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080927/21148174

Comment: I was hoping there was an easier way that didn't involve eventlisteners