# Making text unselectable in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable) I've found how to make text unselectable, which works as expected when used inside a div and stuff. However i can not get it to work inside an iframe.

[here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d16gqkyx/4/) showing my problem, the text inside the div with the `unselectable` class is indeed unselectable as expected, but the lorem ipsum on the website is still selectable, despite having the same `unselectable` class

Is this because elements inside `iframe` do not inherit the classes like `<p>` does inside `<div>`?

If that is the case is there a way to make any text inside the iframe unselectable (html/css/javascript)? Or can this only be done from the source code of the page displayed inside the iframe?

setting `pointer-events: none` is not an option either since buttons and stuff should still be interactable

Thank you for your time.

-Remy

Edit: Thanks for pointing me to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217833/8628766), this does indeed also work for disabling selecting.

Comment: You cannot access an iframe from another origin

Answer (score 0):

It's because of cross-origin policies. 
A workaround for this ( not beautiful ) is to iframe the iframe ( from the same origin ) and lock user-selection on that.