# .Net Method for converting String to HTML Escape Characters

Tags: .net, html, encoding, html-escape-characters

I want to convert an e-mail address into HTML Escape Characters as a basic way to try and avoid being harvested by spam-bots. Like mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163628/making-email-addresses-safe-from-bots-on-a-webpage):

> When placing email addresses on a
>   webpage do you place them as text like
>   this:
>
> ```
> joe.somebody@company.com
> ```
>
> or use a clever trick to try and fool
>   the email address harvester bots? For
>   example:
>
> **HTML Escape Characters:**
>
> ```
> &#106;&#111;&#101;&#46;&#115;&#111;&#109;&#101;&#98;&#111;&#100;&#121;&#64;&#99;&#111;&#109;&#112;&#97;&#110;&#121;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;
> ```

I cannot find a .Net method to do so though. The Html.Encode only does the invalid HTML characters such as £$%^& and not letters.

Does a method exist or do I need to write my own?

Many Thanks

Comment: Although your effort is worthy, and this may protect your address from some bots, it won't fool many and the addresses will be on the lists in no time at all.

Comment: well hopefully it will help a bit. It's attempting to make the best out of it as the other methods (make it an image, hide the address and so on) I am not keen on.

Comment: Damien - the problem is that the lists are bought and sold. As soon as you end up on one it's basically over.

Comment: Yes. There is not much that can be done other than removing it completely which I don't want to do. At least this way I am afforded some protection however weak. Plus I learned something cool but HTML character escaping! :D

Comment: "such as £$%^& and not letters." - stop swearing at the computer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything included in the framework, but you could try something like this?

```
public string ConvertToHtmlEntities(string plainText)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(plainText.Length * 6);
    foreach (char c in plainText)
    {
        sb.Append("&#").Append((ushort)c).Append(';');
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use

HttpUtility.HtmlEncode

also see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx

Comment: Yeah. Cheers. But as mentioned this method only does invalid HTML characters and not letters or numbers. It basically has no effect of the e-mail in the html source.

Comment: Oh ok, then I missunderstood you. Sorry.

Comment: Np. Welcome to SO by the way :)

Comment: Was looking for a simple way to do most things and found this - thanks, Philipp.

Answer (score 2):

```
   public   static asciitable getascii()
    {
        asciitable ascii = new asciitable ();
        ascii.AddasciiRow("0", "NUL", "&#000;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("1", "SOH", "&#001;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("2", "STX", "&#002;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("3", "ETX", "&#003;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("4", "EOT", "&#004;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("5", "ENQ", "&#005;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("6", "ACK", "&#006;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("7", "BEL", "&#007;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("8", "BS", "&#008;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("9", "HT", "&#009;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("10", "LF", "&#010;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("11", "VT", "&#011;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("12", "FF", "&#012;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("13", "CR", "&#013;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("14", "SO", "&#014;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("15", "SI", "&#015;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("16", "DLE", "&#016;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("17", "DC1", "&#017;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("18", "DC2", "&#018;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("19", "DC3", "&#019;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("20", "DC4", "&#020;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("21", "NAK", "&#021;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("22", "SYN", "&#022;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("23", "ETB", "&#023;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("24", "CAN", "&#024;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("25", "EM", "&#025;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("26", "SUB", "&#026;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("27", "ESC", "&#027;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("28", "FS", "&#028;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("29", "GS", "&#029;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("30", "RS", "&#030;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("31", "US", "&#031;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("32", " ", "&#32;", " ");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("33", "!", "&#33;", "!");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("34", Convert.ToChar(34).ToString(), "&#34;", "&quot;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("35", "#", "&#35;", "#");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("36", "$", "&#36;", "$");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("37", "%", "&#37;", "%");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("38", "&", "&#38;", "&amp;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("39", "'", "&#39;", "'");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("40", "(", "&#40;", "(");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("41", ")", "&#41;", ")");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("42", "*", "&#42;", "*");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("43", "+", "&#43;", "+");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("44", ",", "&#44;", ",");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("45", "-", "&#45;", "-");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("46", ".", "&#46;", ".");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("47", "/", "&#47;", "/");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("48", "0", "&#48;", "0");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("49", "1", "&#49;", "1");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("50", "2", "&#50;", "2");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("51", "3", "&#51;", "3");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("52", "4", "&#52;", "4");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("53", "5", "&#53;", "5");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("54", "6", "&#54;", "6");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("55", "7", "&#55;", "7");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("56", "8", "&#56;", "8");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("57", "9", "&#57;", "9");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("58", ":", "&#58;", ":");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("59", ";", "&#59;", ";");
        //ascii.AddasciiRow("60", "<", "&#60;", "&lt;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("60", "<", "&#60;", "<");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("61", "=", "&#61;", "=");
        //ascii.AddasciiRow("62", ">", "&#62;", "&gt;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("62", ">", "&#62;", ">");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("63", "?", "&#63;", "?");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("64", "@", "&#64;", "@");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("65", "A", "&#65;", "A");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("66", "B", "&#66;", "B");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("67", "C", "&#67;", "C");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("68", "D", "&#68;", "D");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("69", "E", "&#69;", "E");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("70", "F", "&#70;", "F");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("71", "G", "&#71;", "G");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("72", "H", "&#72;", "H");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("73", "I", "&#73;", "I");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("74", "J", "&#74;", "J");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("75", "K", "&#75;", "K");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("76", "L", "&#76;", "L");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("77", "M", "&#77;", "M");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("78", "N", "&#78;", "N");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("79", "O", "&#79;", "O");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("80", "P", "&#80;", "P");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("81", "Q", "&#81;", "Q");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("82", "R", "&#82;", "R");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("83", "S", "&#83;", "S");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("84", "T", "&#84;", "T");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("85", "U", "&#85;", "U");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("86", "V", "&#86;", "V");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("87", "W", "&#87;", "W");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("88", "X", "&#88;", "X");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("89", "Y", "&#89;", "Y");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("90", "Z", "&#90;", "Z");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("91", "[", "&#91;", "[");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("92", @"\", "&#92;", @"\");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("93", "]", "&#93;", "]");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("94", "^", "&#94;", "^");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("95", "_", "&#95;", "_");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("96", "`", "&#96;", "`");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("97", "a", "&#97;", "a");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("98", "b", "&#98;", "b");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("99", "c", "&#99;", "c");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("100", "d", "&#100;", "d");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("101", "e", "&#101;", "e");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("102", "f", "&#102;", "f");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("103", "g", "&#103;", "g");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("104", "h", "&#104;", "h");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("105", "i", "&#105;", "i");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("106", "j", "&#106;", "j");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("107", "k", "&#107;", "k");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("108", "l", "&#108;", "l");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("109", "m", "&#109;", "m");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("110", "n", "&#110;", "n");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("111", "o", "&#111;", "o");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("112", "p", "&#112;", "p");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("113", "q", "&#113;", "q");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("114", "r", "&#114;", "r");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("115", "s", "&#115;", "s");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("116", "t", "&#116;", "t");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("117", "u", "&#117;", "u");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("118", "v", "&#118;", "v");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("119", "w", "&#119;", "w");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("120", "x", "&#120;", "x");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("121", "y", "&#121;", "y");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("122", "z", "&#122;", "z");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("123", "{", "&#123;", "{");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("124", "|", "&#124;", "|");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("125", "}", "&#125;", "}");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("126", "~", "&#126;", "~");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("127", "", "&#127;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("128", "€", "&#128;", "&euro;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("129", "", "", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("130", "‚", "&#130;", "&sbquo;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("131", "ƒ", "&#131;", "&fnof;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("132", "„", "&#132;", "&bdquo;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("133", "…", "&#133;", "&hellip;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("134", "†", "&#134;", "&dagger;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("135", "‡", "&#135;", "&Dagger;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("136", "ˆ", "&#136;", "&circ;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("137", "‰", "&#137;", "&permil;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("138", "Š", "&#138;", "&Scaron;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("139", "‹", "&#139;", "&lsaquo;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("140", "Œ", "&#140;", "&OElig;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("141", "", "", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("142", "Ž", "&#142;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("143", "", "", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("144", "", "", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("145", "‘", "&#145;", "&lsquo;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("146", "’", "&#146;", "&rsquo;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("147", "“", "&#147;", "&ldquo;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("148", "”", "&#148;", "&rdquo;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("149", "•", "&#149;", "&bull;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("150", "–", "&#150;", "&ndash;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("151", "—", "&#151;", "&mdash;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("152", "˜", "&#152;", "&tilde;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("153", "™", "&#153;", "&trade;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("154", "š", "&#154;", "&scaron;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("155", "›", "&#155;", "&rsaquo;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("156", "œ", "&#156;", "&oelig;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("157", "", "", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("158", "ž", "&#158;", "");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("159", "Ÿ", "&#159;", "&yuml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("160", "", "&#160;", "&nbsp;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("161", "¡", "&#161;", "&iexcl;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("162", "¢", "&#162;", "&cent;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("163", "£", "&#163;", "&pound;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("164", "¤", "&#164;", "&curren;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("165", "¥", "&#165;", "&yen;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("166", "¦", "&#166;", "&brvbar;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("167", "§", "&#167;", "&sect;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("168", "¨", "&#168;", "&uml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("169", "©", "&#169;", "&copy;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("170", "ª", "&#170;", "&ordf;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("171", "«", "&#171;", "&laquo;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("172", "¬", "&#172;", "&not;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("173", "", "&#173;", "&shy;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("174", "®", "&#174;", "&reg;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("175", "¯", "&#175;", "&macr;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("176", "°", "&#176;", "&deg;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("177", "±", "&#177;", "&plusmn;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("178", "²", "&#178;", "&sup2;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("179", "³", "&#179;", "&sup3;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("180", "´", "&#180;", "&acute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("181", "µ", "&#181;", "&micro;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("182", "¶", "&#182;", "&para;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("183", "·", "&#183;", "&middot;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("184", "¸", "&#184;", "&cedil;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("185", "¹", "&#185;", "&sup1;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("186", "º", "&#186;", "&ordm;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("187", "»", "&#187;", "&raquo;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("188", "¼", "&#188;", "&frac14;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("189", "½", "&#189;", "&frac12;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("190", "¾", "&#190;", "&frac34;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("191", "¿", "&#191;", "&iquest;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("192", "À", "&#192;", "&Agrave;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("193", "Á", "&#193;", "&Aacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("194", "Â", "&#194;", "&Acirc;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("195", "Ã", "&#195;", "&Atilde;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("196", "Ä", "&#196;", "&Auml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("197", "Å", "&#197;", "&Aring;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("198", "Æ", "&#198;", "&AElig;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("199", "Ç", "&#199;", "&Ccedil;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("200", "È", "&#200;", "&Egrave;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("201", "É", "&#201;", "&Eacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("202", "Ê", "&#202;", "&Ecirc;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("203", "Ë", "&#203;", "&Euml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("204", "Ì", "&#204;", "&Igrave;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("205", "Í", "&#205;", "&Iacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("206", "Î", "&#206;", "&Icirc;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("207", "Ï", "&#207;", "&Iuml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("208", "Ð", "&#208;", "&ETH;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("209", "Ñ", "&#209;", "&Ntilde;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("210", "Ò", "&#210;", "&Ograve;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("211", "Ó", "&#211;", "&Oacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("212", "Ô", "&#212;", "&Ocirc;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("213", "Õ", "&#213;", "&Otilde;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("214", "Ö", "&#214;", "&Ouml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("215", "×", "&#215;", "&times;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("216", "Ø", "&#216;", "&Oslash;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("217", "Ù", "&#217;", "&Ugrave;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("218", "Ú", "&#218;", "&Uacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("219", "Û", "&#219;", "&Ucirc;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("220", "Ü", "&#220;", "&Uuml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("221", "Ý", "&#221;", "&Yacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("222", "Þ", "&#222;", "&THORN;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("223", "ß", "&#223;", "&szlig;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("224", "à", "&#224;", "&agrave;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("225", "á", "&#225;", "&aacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("226", "â", "&#226;", "&acirc;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("227", "ã", "&#227;", "&atilde;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("228", "ä", "&#228;", "&auml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("229", "å", "&#229;", "&aring;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("230", "æ", "&#230;", "&aelig;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("231", "ç", "&#231;", "&ccedil;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("232", "è", "&#232;", "&egrave;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("233", "é", "&#233;", "&eacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("234", "ê", "&#234;", "&ecirc;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("235", "ë", "&#235;", "&euml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("236", "ì", "&#236;", "&igrave;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("237", "í", "&#237;", "&iacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("238", "î", "&#238;", "&icirc;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("239", "ï", "&#239;", "&iuml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("240", "ð", "&#240;", "&eth;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("241", "ñ", "&#241;", "&ntilde;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("242", "ò", "&#242;", "&ograve;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("243", "ó", "&#243;", "&oacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("244", "ô", "&#244;", "&ocirc;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("245", "õ", "&#245;", "&otilde;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("246", "ö", "&#246;", "&ouml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("247", "÷", "&#247;", "&divide;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("248", "ø", "&#248;", "&oslash;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("249", "ù", "&#249;", "&ugrave;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("250", "ú", "&#250;", "&uacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("251", "û", "&#251;", "&ucirc;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("252", "ü", "&#252;", "&uuml;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("253", "ý", "&#253;", "&yacute;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("254", "þ", "&#254;", "&thorn;");
        ascii.AddasciiRow("255", "ÿ", "&#255;", "&yuml;");

        return ascii;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but it's easy enough to write one...

```
Public Shared Function HtmlEncodeAll(ByVal Value As String) As String
    Dim Builder As New StringBuilder()

    For Each Chr As Char In Value
        Builder.Append("&#")
        Builder.Append(Convert.ToInt32(Chr))
        Builder.Append(";")
    Next

    Return Builder.ToString()
End Function
```