# Is it effective to obfuscate email address by splitting inner html into multiple span elements?

Tags: html, spam-prevention, email-spam

String replacement via jQuery and bidi rtl via CSS were [suggested previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30476576/3516684). The problem with `direction: rtl;` is that if someone copy-pastes the email address, it comes out in reverse:

```
<a href="mailto:address@to.be.replaced.by.jQuery" id="lnkMail">moc.elpmaxe@em</a>
```

Instead of using using rtl, would it be safe to split the inner html of the `<a>` element into multiple `<span>` elements? For example:

```
<a href="mailto:address@to.be.replaced.by.jQuery" id="lnkMail">
    <span>me@</span>
    <span>example</span>
    <span>.com</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) removes all HTML tags, which is a likely thing for a scraping algorithm to do.